# How to display a calculation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to display a simple calculation for how much gas one may need for a trip. I have my logic in my view for now so that I can easily display the value.
Here is the form the user fills out:

```
    <h1>New Trip!</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
        <br>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :content %>
        <%= f.text_area :content %>
        <br>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :mileage %>
        <%= f.number_field :mileage, step: :any %>
        <br>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :mpg %>
        <%= f.number_field :mpg, step: :any %>

        <br>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :amount %>
        <%= f.number_field :amount, step: :any %>

        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to have the value of this calculation displayed next to the roadtrip they created.
Here is what I have in my partial view that displays the user's trips:

```
 <ul>
        <% roadtrips.each do |r| %>
            <li><%= link_to r.title, roadtrip_path(r) %> - <%= r.name%> </li>%
           <p><%= (r.mileage / r.mpg)*2.90 %></p>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
```

When I go to create the trip and click submit I do get a nil error on '/' not sure why because I thought that's how you divide in Ruby.

Controller:

```
class RoadtripsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :redirect_if_not_logged_in

    def new
        if params[:user_id] && @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]) 
            @roadtrip = @user.roadtrips.build
        else
            @roadtrip = Roadtrip.new
        end
        @roadtrip.build_category
    end

    def index
    
        if params[:user_id] && @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]) 
            @roadtrips = @user.roadtrips.alpha
        else
            @error = "That user does not exist" if params[:user_id] 
            @roadtrips = Roadtrip.alpha.includes(:category, :user)
        end
        @roadtrips = @roadtrips.search(params[:q].downcase) if params[:q] && !params[:q].empty?
    @roadtrips = @roadtrips.filter(params[:roadtrip][:category_id]) if params[:roadtrip] && params[:roadtrip][:category_id] != ""
    end
   
    def create   
        #roadtrips belongs to a user
        #this is how you build the user id inside the roadtrips contoller aka making sure its nested
        @roadtrip = current_user.roadtrips.build(roadtrip_params)
        if @roadtrip.save
            redirect_to roadtrips_path
        else 
            render :new
        end
        
    end

    def edit
        @roadtrip = Roadtrip.find_by_id(params[:id])
        redirect_to roadtrips_path if !@roadtrip || @roadtrip.user != current_user
        @roadtrip.build_category if !@roadtrip.category
      end
    
      def update
         @roadtrip = Roadtrip.find_by(id: params[:id])
         redirect_to roadtrips_path if !@roadtrip || @roadtrip.user != current_user
        if @roadtrip.update(roadtrip_params)
          redirect_to roadtrip_path(@roadtrip)
        else
          render :edit
        end
      end

    def show
        @roadtrip = Roadtrip.find_by_id(params[:id])
        redirect_to roadtrips_path if !@roadtrip
    end

    private
    def roadtrip_params
        params.require(:roadtrip).permit(:title, :content, :mileage, :amount, :mpg, :category_id, category_attributes: [:name])
    end
end
```

Comment: hi can you share your controller?

Comment: There maybe a `roadtrip` where `milage` or `mpg` is nil. or you might need to parse them to `int` first. 
check all roadtrips milage and mpg first. 
`roadtrips.pluck(:milage).any?(&:nil)` and check if is there any nil. do the same for `mpg`

Comment: @togi Yes, I can add the controller ^^